# Deserialize JSON in C# (received from a PHP page)

Tags: c#, json

I want to deserialize a json string received from a webpage

I'm using this code to get the json string

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string downloadString = client.DownloadString("http://www.downmasters.com/api.php");
```

But I'm not sure how to convert the string to an array or something equivalent in C# so that I can use it.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) class.

> Serializes objects to the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) and deserializes JSON data to objects. This class cannot be inherited.

You will need to create some objects to serialize from and deserialize to and annotate them with the different [`DataContract` attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms733127.aspx).

Comment: Can you show some coding please, I'm beginner in this and I still don't know how to read msdn efficiently

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSON.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) to do this, here is an example using WebClient like you are currently.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

WebClient client = new WebClient();
string downloadString = client.DownloadString("http://www.downmasters.com/api.php");
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(downloadString );
```

I recently just finished a web app using ASP.NET MVC 4.0 and I ran into some limitations while using `WebClient`, instead I opted for `HttpWebRequest` which gave me more options to fine tune my requests. That said, if all you are doing is using the DownloadString method then WebClient is a great choice.

Answer (score 0):

why not try simply .Split(char[], stringsplitter.none)

you can use chars to split the array into your required type, that's how I always do it.